# Hashicorp Vault UI - Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute ... The resource has been blocked

Tags: user-interface, nginx, reverse-proxy, hashicorp-vault

I am hosting Vault and Consul servers in a private subnet, inside this private subnet I have dedicated instance to serve as a reverse proxy server let's say the instance is called (private_subnet_proxy).

In order to be able to use Consul's and Vault's UIs from the public, I dedicated a public instance to serve as reverse proxy from the public network into the private_subnet_proxy.

The UI from Consul worked fine with the approach I've used (detailed in the configuration of **private-subnet-proxy.conf** and **public-subnet-proxy.conf**
). However, Vault's UI is giving me a strange error when I try to call it.

[image]

```
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://example.com/vault/ui/assets/vendor-170f8056c4a9bc57b01e6b288c9056e5.js' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'Vl+es41l9uLYuOXW/5b17aSw8jo6h94D00opmpuhryY='. The resource has been blocked.
```

Did anyone else have had this issue and may help me with it? I would appreciate any idea or suggestion.

**private-subnet-proxy.conf**

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
  
    

upstream vault {
    server vault_instance:8200;
}

    location  /vault/ui/ {


        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      

        resolver 127.0.0.1;
        allow "127.0.0.1";
        allow "10.10.1.12";
        deny   all;

        proxy_pass http://vault/ui/;
        
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        sub_filter_types text/css text/http;

        sub_filter_once off;
        sub_filter /v1/ /vault_v1/;
        sub_filter /ui/ /vault/ui/;
        sub_filter "rel=\"stylesheet\"" "";




    }

    location /vault_v1/ {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        

        proxy_pass http://vault/v1/;

        sub_filter_types text/css text/http;
        sub_filter_once off;
        sub_filter /v1/ /vault_v1/;
        sub_filter /ui/ /vault/ui/;
        sub_filter "rel=\"stylesheet\"" "";



    }

}
```

**public-subnet-proxy.conf**

```
    server {

        error_page 497 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;

        auth_basic           "Administrator's Area";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/.htpasswd;
        listen 443 default_server ssl;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;


           location /vault/ {


            proxy_pass http://private_subnet_proxy/vault/ui/;



        }

        location /vault_v1/ {



            proxy_pass http://private_subnet_proxy/vault_v1/;
            

        }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps included in this github repo helped me to setup Vault UI behind nginx reverse proxy

https://github.com/Folcky/hashicorp-vault-and-nginx